Based on my long search, I have a detailed answer to this question and would like to answer it for the benefit of the community if it can be opened
I had asked a question about the demonstrated capabilities of the pioneering Mark I Perceptron.
While it generated significant interest from some of the experts, others considered it a bad question and closed it.
However, I retained my curiosity and interest in the subject and have now found a detailed answer to the question from my long search.
Would the experts here be willing to accommodate an imperfect question or help me make it perfect, so that I could answer it for the benefit of the community? If it is possible, please consider re-opening it 

If it doesn't get re-opened, do you have a personal website? You could post your research there.

@wizzwizz4 Thank you for your encouragement  I remember that you were extraordinarily kind and helpful to me with the original question as well. Unfortunately, I don't have a website but can create a blog and write it there. Thanks again for your suggestion

Now that you have an answer, can the question be sharpened up to fit the available answer? The original reason for closure was "needs details or clarity",

@dave Please forgive me, but I am not sure in what way to improve it. Without intending to argue, the question seems clear enough to me and can be answered in great detail as asked. That is the reason I asked for help in either opening it as it is, or improving it as the experts may deem necessary. Please do guide me if you have any suggestions

For future reference, meta discussions hoping to reopen a question aren’t particularly visible; I added a comment from your question to this discussion. Without that, there’s no context for reviewers in the reopen queue.

If the OP is able to provide a comprehensive answer, something entry level would be appreciated. I looked at the Wikipedia page and, yes, the information is all there but some real world examples explained simply would help to explain why it's important. Any article starting with the phrase "[an] algorithm for supervised learning of binary classifiers" is by definition not for layman and probably assumes quite a lot of prior knowledge on the subject.

Exactly where in the wikipedia page does it answer the OP's original question which was about the capabilities of the Mark I Perceptron built?  I asked about this when the original close happened - see my comments here at the question.  I've just looked again at the wikipedia page and see a whole lot of interesting stuff including what the Mark I showed that perceptrons couldn't do but nothing of what the Mark I specifically DID do.  Enlighten me, please.

The question shouldn't have been closed in the first place.  It's a perfectly answerable question that is not answered anywhere obvious, certainly not in that Wikipedia page.  OP was not asking about general capabilities of single-level neural nets, called Perceptrons, the subject of a treatise by Papert and Minsky (that basically destroyed them as a topic of AI research: hah! what a mistake!).  He's asking about a specific hardware embodiment, the Mark I Perceptron, demonstrated in 1958.  What did that thing do? What were it's capabilities?  What was demonstrated? Read the question!

I'm glad to see that the question has been re-opened; I'd be interested to see your answer to it!

Just to add my voice - I'm also glad it's been reopened, and looking forward to reading the answer!

Amazed that the reopened question has already gotten a close vote - someone really has a problem with this perfectly good question and won't even wait for OP to provide his promised answer before raking him again.  Sad.

@davidbak is there a way to lock it open or something?

I can see why someone would vote to close it again, since the close reason was that the question lacked clarity. The promise of a new answer doesn't really solve that.

Lacked clarity?  The original title and the current title (as edited) are both perfectly clear.  How do you find the question unclear?

???? It has nothing to do with me, you'll notice I'm not a close vote. I'm TELLING YOU that the original close vote reason hasn't been addressed (note the edits to the question came before the close https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/posts/27353/revisions). All that's happened is the asker made a grandiose promise of an answer.

ok, Adam, sorry.

@AdamHyland Please forgive me if my promise of an answer appeared "grandiose", it was never my intention. I have spent months studying this topic and just wanted to share my acquired knowledge. The reason for not editing the question was that I had no idea what kind of edits would satisfy the close voters. None of them seemed interested to guide me. The only extraordinarily kind moderator who tried me help me out was not a close voter (wizzwizz4). The question seemed perfectly clear and answerable to me, so I had absolutely no clue in what way to edit it. That is why I requested for help here.
